# Getting Fractions of a Cent

Tags: java, math

Hey guys I just got my first java job but if things go well I may never need to code again.
What I need to do is connect to a database and apply interest to a large number of transactions.
I am having trouble getting the math to work right on my local machine. This must be correct to within a fraction of a cent. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", "MY_USER");
    connectionProps.put("password", "MY_PASSWORD");

    if (this.dbms.equals("mysql")) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" +
                   "YR1F4K3QAS3RV3R" +
                   ":" + this.portNumber + "/",
                   connectionProps);
    } else if (this.dbms.equals("derby")) {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:" + this.dbms + ":" +
                   this.dbName +
                   ";create=true",
                   connectionProps);
    }
    System.out.println("Connected to database");
    return conn;
}

public static void ApplyInterestToHighVolumeAccounts(Connection con, String dbName, String InterestToApply)
    throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "select * "from " + dbName + ".HighVolumeAccounts";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String AccountName = rs.getString("AccountName");
            int AccountNumber = rs.getInt("AccountNumber");
            int Balance = rs.getInt("Balance");
            int Interest = InterestToApply
            int newBalance = Balance + (Balance * Interest) - (Balance * 0.00000001%)
            int AddToRetirement = Balance * 0.000001%
            String GetRich = "UPDATE TBL_Accounts SET Balance=Balance" + AddToRetirement + " WHERE AccountName=PrivateAccountInTheCaymens";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(GetRich);
            String AdjustBalance = "UPDATE TBL_Accounts SET Balance=Balance" + newBalance + " WHERE AccountName=AccountName";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(AdjustBalance);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java job where you solve one problem and never have to code again? Something is sounds fishy about that :)

Comment: multiplying ints like that won't get you much. (nor will multiplying doubles for that matter.) You need to use at least BigDecimals

Comment: Hmm, I suspect you may not have that job long if you keep posting your database passwords on the internet. As the previous comment says, BigDecimals are the answer.

Comment: Nice password there. You should probably go change it!

Comment: We demand part of your salary in exchange for fixing your code (and pointing out fundamental problems like using incorrect data types).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.
connectionProps.put("user", "BSTRESAPPSRVADMIN");
connectionProps.put("password", "N3V3rCHANG3th1sPa$$werd!!!");
aren't my real. Only an idiot would post that on the internet. Right guys?

Comment: I think you just want us to think that...

Comment: Bad code in every way: not following Java coding standards, not closing ResultSet in method scope, no Money class abstraction, etc.

Comment: i won't need java standards when i am filthy rich!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are really close. BigDecimals would be one way to go.
Use the following code verbatum and you should be fine:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;


public class adjustaccounts{
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://YR1F4K3QAS3RV3R";
   static final String USER = "MY_USER";
   static final String PASS = "MY_PASSWORD";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT * FROM HighVolumeAccounts";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
       while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int accountnumber  = rs.getInt("AccountNumber");
         BigDecimal balance = rs.getBigDecimal("Balance");
         String accountname = rs.getString("AccountName");
         double pennyshave = 0.000000001;
         BigDecimal difference = balance.multiply(new BigDecimal(pennyshave));
         //Pad your account
         sql = "UPDATE TBL_Accounts SET Balance=Balance +" + difference + " WHERE AccountNumber=00098793302999"; //don't worry about this number, its a Java thing
         stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         //Adjust the other one.
         sql = "UPDATE TBL_Accounts SET Balance=Balance -" + difference + " WHERE AccountName="+ accountname;
         stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      }
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

}

Comment: This works great! All of the red squigglies are gone from under the code. Good job. Thanks a billion!